# Changing behavior pressing a button?

Tags: javascript

```
<input type="button" value="button1" id="go" onclick='funcion()'\ >
<input type="button" value="change" id="change"\ >
```

how can i change function OnClick in button1 when i press button change?

Comment: Set a variable in the `change` button's click handler, and examine the variable in `funcion()`.

Comment: Could you provide more details about what you're trying to do? What behavior do you want to change?

Comment: for example.. first time when i press button1 show me "1" with an alert, then i press button "change" that change what button1 do.. changing its function

Answer (score 0):

```
document.getElementById("change").onclick = function() { // when clicking #change
    document.getElementById("go").onclick = function() { // overide the click event listener of #go
        // ...
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<input type="button" value="button1" id="go" onclick='funcion()'\ >
<input type="button" value="change" id="change" onclick='funcion=newFuncion'\>

<script>
    function funcion() {
        //first action
    }

    function newFuncion() {
        //second action
    }
</script>
```